# How to force user to input a fixed amount of numbers for int?

Tags: java, validation, int

I want to force the user to input a number with 5 lengths long (
no more and no less) and store them inside an int variable, this includes a leading 0.

For example, the program should allow the user to input:

```
12345
04123
00012
```

But it should not work for:

```
123456
4123
001
```

I tried...

```
  if(int x < 99999){
  //continue with code
  }
```

This would work only if the user input more than 5 lengths but it doesn't resolve the issue of the user putting in an int length less than 5

Comment: Try taking a `String` input and then check the length. If length is valid then parse it to `Integer`.

Comment: Slightly different take on the above comment...  I would check to see if you can cast to a number first, if that works, then count the size of the values in the string.  It is slightly pedantic, but we always validate the following way.  Not Null, correct type, correct value(s), correct against any persistence store you might be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should take input in string not in int then if the validation goes right you can parse it into integer like the following:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /// take input
    String userInput = "";
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    userInput = sc.nextLine();
    int input ;
    // validation test
    if(userInput.length() == 5) {
        input = Integer.parseInt(userInput);
    }else {
        // you can display an error message to user telling him that he should enter 5 numbers!
    }
}

}
```

but you have to know that after parsing it into int if there's a leading zeros it could be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Something crazy simple like this. Lacks edge case handling (Read: Negative values)

```
boolean matchesLength(int n, int lengthLim){
    char[] charArr = (n + "").toCharArray();
    return (charArr.length == lengthLim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two functions. First, to verify the input:

```
static boolean is_valid_number(String x) {
    // returns true if the input is valid; false otherwise
    if(x.length != 5 || Integer.valueOf(x) > 99999) {  
        // Check that both:
        //    - input is exactly 5 characters long
        //    - input, when converted to an integer, is less than 99999
        // if either of these are not true, return false
        return false;
    }
    // otherwise, return true
    return true;
}
```

and second, to get user input:

```
static int get_user_input() {
    // Create a scanner to read user input from the console
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String num = "";
    do {
        // Continuously ask the user to input a number
        System.out.println("Input a number:");
        num = scanner.next();
        // and continue doing so as long as the number they give isn't valid
    } while (!is_valid_number(num));
    return Integer.valueOf(num);
```

You might also have to do some error-handling, in case the given input isn't an integer at all. You could implement `is_valid_number()` concisely like this:

```
static boolean is_valid_number(String x) {
    try {
        return (x.length == 5 && Integer.valueOf(x) <= 99999);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Integer.valueOf(x) throws this when the string can't be converted to an integer
        return false;
    }
}
```